# How did Lee's personal experience affect the narrative of To Kill A Mockingbird?

Tags: harper-lee, to-kill-a-mockingbird

Many Southern authors of Harper Lee's time period wrote very autobiographical works. This led me to wonder how much Harper Lee's personal life was reflected in the narrative of *To Kill A Mockingbird*. After some research, I was not able to find much. However, I found some information to suggest that she had lived near the location of an event like the one written about in *To Kill A Mockingbird*; her father was a lawyer, like Atticus; she was a tomboy, like Scout; and she had a neighbor down the street who left things in trees, similar to what Boo Radley does in the book. I have not found sources that go into a greater analysis of the similarities. This leads me to ask:

**How did Lee's personal experience affect the narrative of *To Kill A Mockingbird*?**

Comment: Where did you find that information?

Comment: @muru Reading Harper Lee's wikipedia page and [this](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-influenced-harper-lee-write-novel-kill-389305).

Comment: the second link seems to be paywalled. Wikipedia goes on to quote Truman Capote for another similarity.

Comment: @muru I will try to add that in, as to the other link, I don't have an account, but I can view it.

Comment: The book takes place in Alabama, and the author grew up in Monroeville, Alabama. Atticus Finch is an attorney who defends a Black man accused of rape. The author's father is an attorney who defended two Black men accused of murdering a white storekeeper.

Comment: homework.study.com, article: "Who is the defense attorney in To Kill a Mockingbird?"